# Questions with pictures of code

Tags: discussion, feature-request, code-formatting, images

I am sure many of you have seen several questions where the OP posts a picture of their code instead of copy and pasting. Is it possible to have a small warning or such present when the user is uploading their picture, that informs them not to post pictures of code?

Comment: Doubtful if this is possible...how would the system know its an image of code rather than an image of, say, *a unicorn*?

Comment: Do you need to know @Paulie_D? I guess a blanket warning shown underneath the upload picture dialog should do? Depends on how clean the SO people want to keep the interface

Comment: But then you are throwing a warning at **every user** who wants to upload an image. That's annoying to the majority who *don't* post images of code. If they won't read the basic instructions anyway about how to ask a good question...they're certainly not going to pay any attention to another warning.

Comment: Relevant: http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/ImageOfAnException